# React.js Authorization and protected routes

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, authorization

In my application I've a problem with the login system. I'm done with the authentication, but I've 4 different users (patient, doctor, admin, hospital), I want to give authorization based on the user value. if the user === 'doctor' -> Navigate to='/doctor-dashboard', and so on. my question here is how to give authorization to each user after he logs in

I don't know how to give authorization, but I'm using react-router-dom v6.21.1